# Живой поиск на jsp

Tags: javascript, java, веб-программирование, jsp

Подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли на jsp страницах реализовывать живой поиск? Знаю что обычно живой поиск делается AJAX-ом, но как прикрутить его к джаве не нашёл(

Comment: Что за "живой поиск" ?

Comment: @KryTer_NexT ну когда пользователь вводит в строку поиска слово и сразу по первым буквам всплывает снизу окно предлагающее слова содержащие эту последовательность букв (очень плохо объясняю)! К примеру строка поиска гугла, предлагающая варианты поиска!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

То, что называете "Живой поиск" называется обычно Autocomplete, встречается ещё  Suggestbox.

AJAX к жаве не прикручивается. Ему в общем-то всё равно жава там или пхп. И жаба не знает кто выполняет запрос AJAX или Вы сами в браузере открываете адрес.

Если не хотите реализовать свой живой поиск с нуля (что весьма сложно для нуба), то стоит освоить какое-нибудь готовое решение. Их много. Чаще ставят в пример jquery.  Уж не знаю почему. Вроде и напридумали каких-то более годных для этого штук. Но раз jquery, то jquery.

Ваш какой-нибудь `form.jsp` должен сформировать страницу подобную этой (чуть-чуть модифицированный пример с https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Remote datasource</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  .ui-autocomplete-loading {
    background: white url("images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }
 
    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
      source: "search.jsp",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
  <input id="birds">
</div>
 
<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
  Result:
  <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Можете в этом тексте найти `$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({source: "search.jsp",...`
Это указывает, что autocimplete jquery должен за подсказками обращаться с помощью AJAX к `search.jsp` (в оригинале был search.php).
`search.jsp` в свою очередь должен понимать параметр term, в котором передаётся набранная в поле ввода строка и выдавать ответ в виде JSON.
На сервер приходит GET запрос `search.jsp?term=abc`
search.jsp может быть таким

```
<% response.setContentType("application/json"); %>

[
   "${param["term"]", 
   "${param["term"]def", 
   "${param["term"]zxc"
]
```

Я jsp не очень хорошо знаю, так что ошибки возможны. Но суть, считаю, должна быть ясна.